# date() when page load and after submiting form

Tags: php, date

I'm making an registration page and I want to get the timestamp from (A) when the page is loaded and (B) when the form is submited.

In my script I have placed the (A) `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` first in the script and (B) `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` inside the if(isset...)

The problem is that the first date() gets deleted and replaced with the stamp from when I submit the form - and (A) and (B) gets the same.

Is there any way to get this to work simple? Or must I use cookies for an example?

--

This is an example code:

```
<?php

$timepageload = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

    if(isset($_POST['action'])) {

                $timewhensubmited = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

        }

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can see the problem better ?

Comment: I have placed an example code, that show the problem better.

Comment: use `$_POST['action']`

Comment: Thanks. Just a fault in the translation. Original script is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches you can choose.

The most strait-forward one is to include a hidden field in your form which is holding the timestamp.

This actually will be the timestamp A, and the timestamp B can be obtain as you are doing right now.

Comment: Duh! What a simple, but perfect solution (for me). Thanks!

Comment: :D no worries, please don't forget to accept the answer and up-vote, if it was helpful ;)